# Call a variable function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my `app.js` I have defined functions like this:

```
var func1 = function(v1,v2,v3) {
  .
  .
}

var func2 = function(v1,v2,v3) {
  .
  .
}
```

In my `controller.js`:

```
var action = "";

if(..) { action = 'func1';}
else {action = 'func2'}

action(a1,a2,a3);
```

However, I get an error, saying that action is not a function. How can I access `func1` and func2`` like this?

Comment: try `action=func1 ... action=func2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try removing quotes, like, change:

```
if(..) { action = 'func1';}
else {action = 'func2'}
```

to

```
if(..) { action = func1;}
else {action = func2;}
```

Added:
you are assigning string to your action variable when you add quotes for the `func1`, you can check it doing:

```
var func1 = function(v1,v2,v3) {
  alert("first");
};
var test_this = func1;
console.log( typeof test_this); //gives you function
```

where as

```
var test_this = 'func1'; //with quotes added
console.log( typeof test_this); //gives you string
```

Comment: Works ..thank you.. can you explain why it is like this? In normal javascript we actually use ''.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal quotes denote a string. It seems that `action` wants a function.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Oh! I was actually thinking on the basis of javascript ..:)

Comment: unless `func1` and `func2` are global, `action` cannot access the function by name anyways. It's rare to identify a function by name in javascript - it would have to be accessed as `window[name]` (in a browser) or `global[name]` (everywhere else)

Comment: func1 and func2 are global as they are in app.js. What do you mean by global[name] (everywhere else)?? I have only used the window version

Comment: An alternative would be to store the functions in an array or hash. Then you can identify them by their index into this array.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal if you are in a non-browser environment like Node.js, `window` is not the global object.

Comment: @JanDvorak- Yes that too can be done ..but for two functions creating an array and then accessing the arrya would be more taxing and not required

Comment: @BhumiSinghal if you want to encode polymorphic behavior into JSON, you'd encode the function as an index to some look-up table. `{"action":"add", "args":[1,2]}`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the function from a string. I'm no expert but you could just try

```
if (..) {
    func1(a1, a2, a3);
} else {
    func2(a1, a2, a3);
}
```

Comment: actually this is something that is like the basics of programming but i cant do it . I need to access using a var. Thanks